# Gatsby.js: how to migrate all *.js files to *ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, gatsby

I'm actively migrating my personal website from pure React to Gatsby. Doing good so far.

Being a TypeScript fan, I make use of it already. One question I have however is ***whether there's a way to use TypeScript for Gatsby's configuration files or not (`gatsby-browser.js`, `gatsby-config.js`, `gatsby-node.js`, and `gatsby-ssr.js`).*** Same question applies to Gatsby plugin configuration/bootstrap files (e.g. `typography.js`).

Here's what my file system tree looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Whatever files in `src` can be written in `ts`/`tsx`, including `typography.js`.
- All configuration files has to be `.js`, unfortunately. There's nothing to stop you from compiling those config files with `tsc` first though!

Comment: I'm working on implementing such feature (compiling config files into js before gatsby start) in a plugin of mine. If you're interested, [watch it here](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-plugin-ts). It does codegen for your graphql query automatically. I also converted the [blog starter into ts using it here](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-starter-blog-ts).

Comment: Thank you for clarification!